# Ground rod to exterior disconnect panel routing & panel attachment

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding

I'm getting my shop power reconnected after prior storm damage and the inspector said he'd need to see a ground rod connection to the panel. I've included pictures of the existing ground rod though it looks like the ground is/was only connected to the plumbing.

Towards checking the box for this requirement, can I get some #6 copper and make a new run from the existing rod to the panel? I saw a ground strap to panel-box connection (dark corner of the pictured panel) and imagined I could connect it there, once I sorted out the routing. I read on another post that there can be thread/contact requirements for securing grounds to metal boxes, thus I'm seeking the most efficient yet conductively safe solution.

[image: panel interior]
[image: ground rod & existing copper]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a new rod. *Possibly two.*

To play it safe and so that you don't fail inspection again, I recommend:

- Check with the inspector about what size ground wire you need. 6 AWG may be fine, but you may need 4 AWG. It may depend on the jurisdiction, the inspector or the service feed size, or all of the above.
- Check with the inspector to find out whether they want:

  - One ground rod
  - One ground rod with testing - you're not doing that, *nobody* does
  - Two ground rods - this is extremely common. If you do two ground rods, they use **one** wire that goes to both rods, not a wire from panel to one rod and a separate wire from rod one to rod two.
  - One ground rod *and* a water pipe connection

The rules vary a bit by jurisdiction. Ground rods are inexpensive. My local jurisdiction a year ago required one ground rod + water pipe, but my electrician was prepared with a second ground rod ready to install *if the inspector asked for it* - the "rules" really do vary a bit.

Comment: Thank you for the solid advice leading to the real answer. For context, I didn't fail, the inspector mentioned it as I got my temp tag. I'll contact him again to verify my proposed solution will work on his end. I like the idea of a thicker conductor & new ground rod; if anything else is required I'll add another comment though as you pointed out it varies by locality.